# Is there a way to control how pressing the TAB key works on angular?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

Can i change the behaviour when moving through elements in my html page with tab? Like which element is the first one to be focused when pressing `TAB` key?

**FYI** the SPA app is created using Angular as a framework.

**Well:**

- I know the existence of `tabindex` but it does not work when using a custom UI like [ng-zorro](https://ng.ant.design/docs/introduce/en) which is the one i am using.
- I think that ng-zorro is overriding `tabindex` or tab property behavior.(there is something in their github file...)
- I could get the element and from my ts do something with `onFocus()` ?

I honeslty do not know any help?

**EDIT**
If you want there is [ng-zorro-select](https://ng.ant.design/components/select/en) with which you can try to use any of the would work they have a stackblitz for every example... So say you have three ng-zorro select how do you set the tab order?

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mghc4t?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Could you explain what exactly you are trying to achieve

Comment: I want to control what element of my page gets focused when pressing `tab` (like buttons etc). I tried to use `tabindex` but it didn't work

Comment: Please provide more details in your question. “It didn’t work” is not very helpful. What did you expect, what happens instead? If you would have some example code, or even better a [Minimal Reproducbile Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in a code snippet, you could avoid the question being closed.

Comment: Okay i added some extra code

Comment: I would want to set the `tab` order when i have multiple elements but using `tabindex="1"` does not work...

Comment: You could add a property to keep track of which key order you are at. Set a listener to tab and set focus on the specific element if it matches with your property.

Comment: Your code still does not demonstrate how you are trying to set `tabindex`. Anyway, `<nz-select>` itself does not receive focus, but a `<input>` child. And NG-Zorro does not allow you to pass down that attribute via its API. I don’t know what problem you’re trying to solve but [it’s strongly discouraged to use tabindex>0](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex#sect2) as then you’d need to manually set `tabindex` for all elements on the page, or it results in confusing interfaces. Putting elements in the right DOM order is the recommended way.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a `viewChild` and trigger focus method, if you want it inbuilt, raise a request in the `ngzorro` github repo.

ts

```
import { ChangeDetectorRef, Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { NzSelectComponent } from 'ng-zorro-antd/select';

@Component({
  selector: 'nz-demo-select-search',
  template: `
    <nz-select #firstFocus nzShowSearch nzAllowClear nzPlaceHolder="Select a person" [(ngModel)]="selectedValue">
      <nz-option nzLabel="Jack" nzValue="jack"></nz-option>
      <nz-option nzLabel="Lucy" nzValue="lucy"></nz-option>
      <nz-option nzLabel="Tom" nzValue="tom"></nz-option>
    </nz-select>
  `,
  styles: [
    `
      nz-select {
        width: 200px;
      }
    `,
  ],
})
export class NzDemoSelectSearchComponent {
  @ViewChild('firstFocus', { static: true }) firstFocus: NzSelectComponent;
  selectedValue = null;

  constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.firstFocus.focus();
    this.cdr.detectChanges();
  }
}
```

[forked stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6uwcxp)

Comment: If I understand correctly, this establishes an auto-focus, but does not control it’s order.

Comment: @Andy inside the ng-zorro components there will be an input field, with default tab index, so tabbing should work, if not, its a fault with the library and should be reported in the github issues page!

Comment: Thanks for replying, yes this does control focus but does not control the order in which the select is going to be focused... if i have multiple selects i can't control the order of focus. But still this was very helpful thanks!